# Problem with using IntermediateSerializer outside an XNA project

Tags: wpf, xml-serialization, xna

I'm currently working on an Xbox360 game. In this game I have lots of data stored in XML. Deserializing it through IntermediateSerializer in the XNA Game project is no problem, works like a charm. But since these structures stored in XML can be quite complicated I decided to make a simple editor for the stuff, so I (or maybe a less experienced user) could edit the objects visualy (animations, game stages etc) rather than having to write these data as XML. Then I would serialize it through the IntermediateSerializer and everything would be fine.

For this editor I created a WPF project, and referenced the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.dll

Visual Studio recognizes the IntermediateSerializer class, and intellisense helpfully recommends to use the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Serialization.Intermediate namespace, but I keep getting the following error message:

The type or namespace name 'Pipeline' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

(I'm using XNA 4.0 and .NET 4)

Am I doing something wrong or is this just simply impossible?

Tenshiko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Application Properties ensure
   that the *Target framework* is set to
   **.NET Framework 4**.

By default a new WPF application targets the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.  The Client Profile is designed to reduce the download size of the .NET Framework for end users and excludes assemblies that are only used in development.  In your case Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.dll depends on Microsoft.Build.Framework and Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0 which are not available in the Client Profile.

Comment: That's a satisfying answer, thanks. But there's still something I shouldn't have overlooked: though MSDN mentions only the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.dll, the namespace is devided to a few other assemblies, and I needed to use them too!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you did set a target framework of your WPF application to ".NET Framework 4". It has to help.

Comment: I also have an "Xbox360 Library" project, which I use in the WPF project (and it works), so I tried moving the whole serialization method there, but I have the same problem there too.